# rEFInd successfully installed, but Ubuntu still doesn't show up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac, refind

I've been crawling through getting Ubuntu installed on my Mac. I'd like to have it dualboot but keep running into small issues. So far ...

-rEFInd shows on my mac! SIP is disabled and launches with every boot, so no stress there 
- I've managed to properly format and use the space on the drive to run Ubuntu, and can see the content in the "try ubuntu" os, so i know it's installed
- when i boot and have my options, it shows the USB loader just fine, shows my mac os just fine, but no ubuntu
- when i first installed rEFInd, the install of ubuntu on my internal ssd showed and booted without issue

- internal ssd is 500 gb, 16gb ram.
- There are 3 partitons on the internal SSD - the macOS (250gb), Ubuntu, and a 4gb FAT for easy data transfer between the two
- it stopped showing the ubuntu partition after booting to the macOS (nothing was installed!), but still launches into rEFInd without issue

Is it possible I need to configure something to get the installed drive recognized? I'm still new and learning, and didn't realize I needed rEFInd until after my initial boot (which, again, after first installing it showed ubuntu).

[I've seen similar posts with people having similar issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983282/usb-flash-drive-ubuntu-install-not-showing-up-in-refind-on-mac), but no luck in solutions. If you have any advice or need any further information, please let me know!